# A Bayesian problem of coin tossing

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A box contains $3$ coins . Among these three , each of  two coins have the probability of giving head $\dfrac 23$ and the remaining one have the probability of turning head $\dfrac 12$ . One coin is chosen randomly from the box and tossed three times and each time it turns out to be head . What is the probability that the coin chosen from the box was the unbiased one i.e. the one with head probability $\dfrac 12$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Probability that you select a biased coin is $\frac23$.  Probability of a biased coin coming up HHH in three tosses is $\frac{8}{27}$.

Probability that you select the unbiased coin is $\frac13$.  Probability of the unbiased coin coming up HHH in three tosses is $\frac18$.

See if you can take it from here!